# Settings' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I got the exception and can't figure it out.

> Settings = '((BandwidthRestriction.Models.SettingRespository)settingRespository).Settings' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'

I have two tables.

```
namespace BandwidthRestriction.Models
{
    [Table("Settings")]
    public class Setting
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public string Classification { get; set; }
        public virtual FacilitySettingOverride FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace BandwidthRestriction.Models
{
    [Table("FacilitySettingOverride")]
    public class FacilitySettingOverride
    {
        [Key]
        public int FacilityId { get; set; }
        public int SettingId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Another table

```
namespace BandwidthRestriction.Models
{
    [Table("Facilities")]
    public class Facility
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverrides { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The table's structure likes

[![12][1]][1]

Also I have the correspond dbcontext as

```
 public class SettingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=11.53.63.94;Initial Catalog=AAA;User ID=sa;password=password;Application Name=XXX");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

In the respository, I have

```
namespace BandwidthRestriction.Models
{
    public class SettingRespository : ISettingRespository
    {
       public List<Setting> GetAllSettings()
       {
          return Settings.ToList();
       }

       public IEnumerable<Setting> Settings
       {
           get
           {
               List<Setting> settingList;
               using (SettingDbContext context = new SettingDbContext())
               {
                   settingList = context.Settings.ToList();
               }
               return settingList;
           }
        }
```

In the controller, I passed the DI.

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 public class BandwidthController : Controller
 {
     private readonly ISettingRespository _settingRespository;

     public BandwidthController(ISettingRespository settingRespository)
     {
         _settingRespository = settingRespository;
     }
```

However when I hover the `_settingRespository`. I see the exception:

> Settings = '((BandwidthRestriction.Models.SettingRespository)settingRespository).Settings' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

**EDIT:**

Per the comment, I fixed the table name misspelling issue. The error is `SqlException: Invalid column name 'FacilitySettingOverrideSettingId'`, But I found a similar question at [stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142186/entity-framework-5-invalid-column-name-reverse-engineer-code-first) Maybe I used code first wrongly?

In another word, the table **FacilitySettingOverride**, it doesn't have the primary key. Is it the cause?

**EDIT-1**

Per comments. I redesigned the DB. I think that `Setting-FacilitySettingOverride to be 1:1`
[![new][3]][3]

And

```
 [Table("FacilitySettingOverride")]
 public class FacilitySettingOverride
 {
    [Key]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int SettingId { get; set; }

    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
}
```

The new error is

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'FacilityId1'.

in the code:

```
    public int GetFacilityBandwidthSetting(int facilityId)
    {
        using (SettingDbContext context = new SettingDbContext())
        {
            var setting = context.Settings.Single(s => s.Name == SettingType.TotalBandwidth.ToString());
            var value = context.FacilitySettingOverride.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FacilityId == facilityId
                && x.SettingId == setting.Id);
            if (value == null)
                return int.Parse(setting.DefaultValue);
            return int.Parse(value.Value);
        }
    }
```

and

```
 [Table("Facilities")]
 public class Facility
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

I can getting `Setting` but `FacilitySettingOverride` in the context.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: @tofutim. No inner exception. Just a red X. The exception implied ` get
            {
                List<Setting> settingList;
                using (SettingDbContext context = new SettingDbContext())
                {
                    settingList = context.Settings.ToList();
                }
                return settingList;
            }` is the error's location

Comment: is the Settings table in the dB?

Comment: Yes, it is in the DB. I just found the unhandled exception `InvalidOperationException: The navigation 'FacilitySettingOverrides' on entity type 'BandwidthRestriction.Models.Facility' has not been added to the model, or ignored, or target entityType ignored.`

Comment: Is it possible that the table declaration should be [Table("FacilitySettingOverrides")] instead of [Table("FacilitySettingOverride")]?

Comment: @tofutim, No. I doubt the POCO class is wrong. Maybe need foreign key attribute but not sure.

Comment: the DB says that the Table is "FacilitySettingsOverride" as does the POCO, but the DBContext says FacilitySettingsOverrides

Comment: @tofutim, if I change it, the error still there. The exception becomes `SqlException: Invalid column name 'FacilitySettingOverrideSettingId'.`

Comment: a change in exception is a good sign - why do you think it is looking for "FacilitySettingOverrideSettingId"?

Comment: i think the virtual table needs to correspond to an id in the POCO

Comment: @tofutim, I didn't list all code because of space. The exception is got from a httpget in controller `http://localhost:50505/api/Bandwidth/GetTotalBandwidth/1`. I reattached the image. And I think the POCO class `FacilitySettingOverride` or others might be wrong to cause the issue.

Comment: @GertArnold, as I said. Just sticking on the database schema(image). I can remove `public virtual FacilitySettingOverride FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }` from `Setting` class. But the error is still there. Also there is another error `nvalidOperationException: The entity type 'BandwidthRestriction.Models.FacilitySettingOverride' requires a key to be defined.`. So I guess the root error is that there is no PK in the table? But I can't find the document to verify my theory.

Comment: Yes, you should always have a PK in the table. Here is a good thread on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key

Comment: Has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37398577/861716) now I guess?

Comment: @GertArnold, yes. You can place an answer here.

Comment: If you still need an answer here, please sanitize the question. It isn't really clear what your asking any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create POCO class in EF 7 code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398577/create-poco-class-in-ef-7-code-first)

Basically they are same question. The key issue is to create the correct POCO class.