# Create POCO class in EF 7 code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Say I have three tables. Settings, Facilities and FacilitySettingOverride in an existing database. The sample data:

```
Settings table

ID   Name     Value
1    test1    true
2    test2    true

Facilities table

ID    Name
163   Demo1
164   Demo2

FacilitySettingOverride
FacilityId      SettingId   Value
163               2         False
164               1         False
164               2         False
```

FacilitySettingOverride has two foreign keys---FacilityId and SettingId. Also I want to make a composite key for FacilitySettingOverride.

I just don't know how to make it. My primary code.

```
[Table("Settings")]
public class Setting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public FacilitySettingOverride FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }
}

[Table("Facilities")]
public class Facility
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public  virtual ICollection<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverrides { get; set; }
}

[Table("FacilitySettingOverride")]
public class FacilitySettingOverride
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("FacilityId")]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SettingId")]
    public int SettingId { get; set; }

    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
```

I guess that it is wrong. Thanks for help.

Comment: If you have a database, you can generate a model using `Scaffold-DbContext` command. Why do you try to use Code First?

Comment: I am not familiar with the command.

Comment: So is this an override :) of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37354780/861716)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data and description, both `Settings` and `Facility` have one-to-many associations to `FacilitySettingOverride`. So `Setting` shouldn't have a property ...

```
public FacilitySettingOverride FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }
```

... but a collection of `FacilitySettingOverride`s, just as `Facility` has.

This should be the proper class model:

```
[Table("Settings")]
public class Setting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverrides { get; set; }
}

[Table("Facilities")]
public class Facility
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverrides { get; set; }
}

[Table("FacilitySettingOverride")]
public class FacilitySettingOverride
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Facility")]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Setting")]
    public int SettingId { get; set; }

    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The combination of `KeyAttribute` and `ColumnAttribute` (`[Key, Column(Order = 1)]`) is used for composite primary keys.

This is the database schema EF creates from it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you save my life.